# How to send bulk text SMS

Tags: c#, asp.net, sms, gsm

Dears I know this question may be asked before but actually i didn't find what are the steps should be made to how sending a bulk text SMS to cell phones through asp application.

I’m using asp.net on C# web application.
I want to send the SMS locally in Egypt.

Thanks to give me your support...

Comment: you need to pay to use an SMS service - twilio for example: https://www.twilio.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an sms api. But for these you have to pay money . but some provide you limited free sms like 25 sms. After that you have to pay money. Just have a try. it s simple to use in your application.

some are :

http://redoxygen.com/products/red-api/

https://www.twilio.com/